JMeter: OutOfMemoryError with Large JMX Files
I'm encountering severe issues when attempting to open JMX files larger than 2MB or with large payloads in JMeter. The application becomes unresponsive and utilizes a high amount of CPU. When I do manage to open the file and try to execute a test with 1 user and 1 loop, I frequently get the error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space."
What I've tried:

Increased the Java heap space to the maximum available limit in the properties file.
Uninstalled and reinstalled JMeter.
Upgraded to the latest version of JMeter.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Your test plan is doing something that uses a lot of help memory, but we don't know what it is. Share a [mre]. Also, what does it mean "Increased the Java heap space to the maximum available limit"? We don't know what are your limits or what number did you use. Be specific and explicit. Read [ask].

Maximum Java heap space available for JMeter is configured either via HEAP environment variable or line like this:
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m

in jmeter.bat startup script
So you either need to set this variable or edit the startup script. JMeter restart will be required in order to pick up the change.
More information: 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure
